# remove eval of variable in javascript and get alternate code

Tags: javascript

There's a code form other people, and there's some `eval` usage like this:

```
var obj1 = null;
var obj2 = null;
var obj3 = null;

//... after many lines ...
var idx=3;  //get from UI, from user selection, etc.
** var curObj = eval('obj'+idx);  // now curObj is one of obj1,obj2,obj3

//using curObj below
```

Question: how to remove `eval` part in **line, and found a substitution with minimum modification to dynamicly get `obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3` from `idx` value?

**Update 1**

Tried add **array** as below:

```
var obj1 = null;
var obj2 = null;
var obj3 = null;
[+] var objArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
```

But this way `objArray` is a **constant** array not a **reference** array, any time I trace the `objArray` the value is `[null,null,null]`; I know if any time I update `obj1-3` I should also update the `objArray`, but it's not practical, since there'are so many assignment in the code.

Can show the right `objArray` working code to dynamic get `obj1-3` anytime?

Comment: I would use an array and put those objects in the same order

Comment: If the original programmer was doing this kind of thing, there is a good chance the code is full of other bad practices. If it's an option for you, consider rewriting this part of the code.

Comment: Having multiple variables of the form `somethingX` where `X` is a number is a strong indicator for using an array instead. Learn about arrays: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Comment: You don't show what you are doing to `objX`, but you would simply replace *any* reference to any of these variables with `objArray[X]`, or at least mutate the object itself (assume the values will be objects) instead of assign a new value to the variable.